# LAPACK's zgesvd results different than scipy.linalg's SVD

Tags: python, c, linear-algebra, lapack, lapacke

So I'm trying to compute SVD of an `NxN` matrix. Strangely, for all the cases of `2x2` matrices, the SVD from both lapack and scipy match but they differ when I go for a `3x3` or `4x4` matrices.

```
// LAPACK (C) Case: 2x2

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

/* Complex datatype */
struct _dcomplex { double re, im; };
typedef struct _dcomplex dcomplex;

/* ZGESVD prototype */
extern void zgesvd( char* jobu, char* jobvt, int* m, int* n, dcomplex* a,
                   int* lda, double* s, dcomplex* u, int* ldu, dcomplex* vt, int* ldvt,
                   dcomplex* work, int* lwork, double* rwork, int* info );
/* Auxiliary routines prototypes */
extern void print_matrix( char* desc, int m, int n, dcomplex* a, int lda );
extern void print_rmatrix( char* desc, int m, int n, double* a, int lda );

/* Parameters */
#define M 2
#define N 2
#define LDA M
#define LDU M
#define LDVT N

/* Main program */
int main() {
    /* Locals */
    int m = M, n = N, lda = LDA, ldu = LDU, ldvt = LDVT, info, lwork;
    dcomplex wkopt;
    dcomplex* work;
    /* Local arrays */
    /* rwork dimension should be at least max( 1, 5*min(m,n) ) */
    double s[M], rwork[5*M];
    dcomplex u[LDU*M], vt[LDVT*N];
//    dcomplex a[LDA*N] = {
//        {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1,  0},
//        {-0.36599657,  -0.27449743}, {-0.27449743,  0.36599657}, {0.76249285, 0},
//        {-0.36599657, 0.27449743}, {-0.27449743, -0.36599657}, {0.76249285, 0},
//    };
    dcomplex a[LDA*N] = {
        {0.70710678, 0}, {0, -0.70710678},
        {0.70710678,  0}, {0,  0.70710678},
    };
    /* Executable statements */
    printf( " ZGESVD Example Program Results\n" );
    /* Query and allocate the optimal workspace */
    lwork = -1;
    zgesvd( "All", "All", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &ldu, vt, &ldvt, &wkopt, &lwork,
           rwork, &info );
    lwork = (int)wkopt.re;
    work = (dcomplex*)malloc( lwork*sizeof(dcomplex) );
    /* Compute SVD */
    zgesvd( "All", "All", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &ldu, vt, &ldvt, work, &lwork,
           rwork, &info );
    /* Check for convergence */
    if( info > 0 ) {
        printf( "The algorithm computing SVD failed to converge.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    /* Print singular values */
    print_rmatrix( "Singular values", 1, m, s, 1 );
    /* Print left singular vectors */
    print_matrix( "Left singular vectors (stored columnwise)", m, m, u, ldu );
    /* Print right singular vectors */
    print_matrix( "Right singular vectors (stored rowwise)", m, n, vt, ldvt );
    /* Free workspace */
    free( (void*)work );
    exit( 0 );
} /* End of ZGESVD Example */

/* Auxiliary routine: printing a matrix */
void print_matrix( char* desc, int m, int n, dcomplex* a, int lda ) {
    int i, j;
    printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        printf( " (%6.2f,%6.2f)", a[i+j*lda].re, a[i+j*lda].im );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

/* Auxiliary routine: printing a real matrix */
void print_rmatrix( char* desc, int m, int n, double* a, int lda ) {
    int i, j;
    printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( " %6.2f", a[i+j*lda] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Yields

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
ZGESVD Example Program Results

 Singular values
   1.00   1.00

 Left singular vectors (stored columnwise)
 ( -0.71,  0.00) ( -0.71,  0.00)
 ( -0.00,  0.71) (  0.00, -0.71)

 Right singular vectors (stored rowwise)
 ( -1.00, -0.00) ( -0.00, -0.00)
 ( -0.00, -0.00) ( -1.00, -0.00)
```

and `scipy.linalg.SVD` yields

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
Singular values: [1. 1.]
Left singular vectors: [[-0.70710678+0.j         -0.70710678+0.j        ]
                        [ 0.        +0.70710678j  0.        -0.70710678j]]
Right singular vectors: [[-1.+0.j -0.+0.j]
                         [-0.+0.j -1.+0.j]]
```

So far so good. Now when I try to input a `3x3` or `NxN` matrix, the results are like

```
// LAPACK C Case: 3x3

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

/* Complex datatype */
struct _dcomplex { double re, im; };
typedef struct _dcomplex dcomplex;

/* ZGESVD prototype */
extern void zgesvd( char* jobu, char* jobvt, int* m, int* n, dcomplex* a,
                   int* lda, double* s, dcomplex* u, int* ldu, dcomplex* vt, int* ldvt,
                   dcomplex* work, int* lwork, double* rwork, int* info );
/* Auxiliary routines prototypes */
extern void print_matrix( char* desc, int m, int n, dcomplex* a, int lda );
extern void print_rmatrix( char* desc, int m, int n, double* a, int lda );

/* Parameters */
#define M 3
#define N 3
#define LDA M
#define LDU M
#define LDVT N

/* Main program */
int main() {
    /* Locals */
    int m = M, n = N, lda = LDA, ldu = LDU, ldvt = LDVT, info, lwork;
    dcomplex wkopt;
    dcomplex* work;
    /* Local arrays */
    /* rwork dimension should be at least max( 1, 5*min(m,n) ) */
    double s[M], rwork[5*M];
    dcomplex u[LDU*M], vt[LDVT*N];
    dcomplex a[LDA*N] = {
        {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1,  0},
        {-0.36599657,  -0.27449743}, {-0.27449743,  0.36599657}, {0.76249285, 0},
        {-0.36599657, 0.27449743}, {-0.27449743, -0.36599657}, {0.76249285, 0},
    };
//    dcomplex a[LDA*N] = {
//        {0.70710678, 0}, {0, -0.70710678},
//        {0.70710678,  0}, {0,  0.70710678},
//    };
    /* Executable statements */
    printf( " ZGESVD Example Program Results\n" );
    /* Query and allocate the optimal workspace */
    lwork = -1;
    zgesvd( "All", "All", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &ldu, vt, &ldvt, &wkopt, &lwork,
           rwork, &info );
    lwork = (int)wkopt.re;
    work = (dcomplex*)malloc( lwork*sizeof(dcomplex) );
    /* Compute SVD */
    zgesvd( "All", "All", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &ldu, vt, &ldvt, work, &lwork,
           rwork, &info );
    /* Check for convergence */
    if( info > 0 ) {
        printf( "The algorithm computing SVD failed to converge.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    /* Print singular values */
    print_rmatrix( "Singular values", 1, m, s, 1 );
    /* Print left singular vectors */
    print_matrix( "Left singular vectors (stored columnwise)", m, m, u, ldu );
    /* Print right singular vectors */
    print_matrix( "Right singular vectors (stored rowwise)", m, n, vt, ldvt );
    /* Free workspace */
    free( (void*)work );
    exit( 0 );
} /* End of ZGESVD Example */

/* Auxiliary routine: printing a matrix */
void print_matrix( char* desc, int m, int n, dcomplex* a, int lda ) {
    int i, j;
    printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        printf( " (%6.2f,%6.2f)", a[i+j*lda].re, a[i+j*lda].im );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

/* Auxiliary routine: printing a real matrix */
void print_rmatrix( char* desc, int m, int n, double* a, int lda ) {
    int i, j;
    printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( " %6.2f", a[i+j*lda] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Yeilds

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
 ZGESVD Example Program Results

 Singular values
   1.55   0.65   0.42

 Left singular vectors (stored columnwise)
 (  0.26,  0.00) (  0.49, -0.34) ( -0.75,  0.00)
 (  0.20, -0.00) ( -0.66,  0.46) ( -0.57,  0.00)
 ( -0.94, -0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) ( -0.33,  0.00)

 Right singular vectors (stored rowwise)
 ( -0.61, -0.00) ( -0.56, -0.00) ( -0.56, -0.00)
 (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.41, -0.58) ( -0.41,  0.58)
 ( -0.79, -0.00) (  0.43, -0.00) (  0.43, -0.00)
```

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
# Python
Singular values: [1.55161905 0.64699664 0.41698163]
Left singular vectors: [[ 0.26480555-9.68622857e-18j  0.57973136-1.54633603e-01j
  -0.75490266+2.76133169e-17j]
 [ 0.19860416+1.15286199e-17j -0.77297515+2.06178138e-01j
  -0.56617699-3.28655711e-17j]
 [-0.94362832+0.00000000e+00j  0.        +0.00000000e+00j
  -0.33100694+0.00000000e+00j]]
Right singular vectors: [[-0.60815722+0.j         -0.5613131 +0.j         -0.5613131 +0.j        ]
 [ 0.        +0.j          0.18223745-0.68321996j -0.18223745+0.68321996j]
 [-0.7938166 +0.j          0.43003209+0.j          0.43003209+0.j        ]]
```

Now for a fact I know that the results computed by Scipy are perfect as the purpose that I'm using SVD for is point perfect and gives perfect results and my goal is to generate results like scipy. Now I know that Scipy also uses LAPACK's Drivers but why the difference then? Where am I messing it up.

Comment: Can you specify the problem? The singular values are the same (upto rounding), are they not? Are your 3x3, nxn matrices non-degenerate? If so, then the left/right vectors are only unique upto a complex phase. If not, then the left/right vectors need not be unique at all.

Comment: Are you sure that scipy calls the same lapack routines?

Comment: @jack In the case of `3x3` or `nxn` we can see that some values are same by rounding off but most of the values are different having a difference of 6 to 7 points. I have examples where only the first row matches but the 2nd or 3rd row don't match at all. There is a high probability that i'm messing up the parameters for LAPACK somehow. Scipy's SVD contains a parameter named `lapack_driver` and i'm giving it the vallue of `gesvd`

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you should be testing is not that the output matrices are the same.

The condition `u @ np.diag(s) @ vh = A` with `u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(A)`, is where you should focus.

Also pay atention to the order of the singular values, if you have two set of singular values s1 and s2 that are the same when sorted, you can construct a matrix P such that `P @ np.diag(s1) @ P.T = s2` if you are lucky you can then use `u1 @ P.inv() = u2` and `P.T.inv() @ vh1 = vh2` since `(u1 @ P.inv()) @ P @ np.diag(s1) @ P.T @ (P.T.inv() @ vh1) = u1 @ np.diag(1) @ vh1`.